# StringUtils.isNotEmpty(str) seems not working properly on hadoop cluster data validation

Tags: hadoop, string-utils

I am not sure and facing strange nullpointer issue as below. could someone please help me on this in the below code

```
 if ((COUNTRY_CODE.equalsIgnoreCase(Country.TEST.name())) && (strCellId.matches("[0-9]*")))
```

is throwing nullpointer in the log file(as per line number). The only offending code i can see is `strCellId.matches("[0-9]*")` if `strCellId` is null

however, `StringUtils.isNotEmpty(strCellId)` is called already before we enter to if condition. please see the condition

```
public static boolean validateCellId(String strCellId)
{
  if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(strCellId)) {
     //here the nullpointer is coming  
    if ((COUNTRY_CODE.equalsIgnoreCase(Country.TEST.name())) && (strCellId.matches("[0-9]*"))) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Null pointer exception at which line? what call?

Comment: I have updated the comment in the code. Also i believe even we call this validateCellId method with null then stringutil should take care and should not allow to enter into inner if condition. please let me know if i am missing something obvious

Comment: Can you provide the stack track? You may forget to initial the `COUNTRY_CODE` or `Country.TEST`.

Comment: its my bad. my Country was not initialized. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its My Bad .
 @zsxwing you are right. My country was not initialized, i should have check this, i just overlooked it with confidence.Thanks